# playing with head in ubuntu

Tags: command-line

Hi while I am playing with Ubuntu head command of CLI, I came to a situation.There what ever I am giving as input thats echoing automatically.

The command and its play mentioned in the image.

so could somebody explain me whats happening in there ? 
[image].

**Note**: here h.txt is a general text file I made with raw information.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. You mean that after you type too much, `head` does not stop echoing (i.e. it behaves like `cat`)? That would be a very odd bug, maybe try with `head -n1 -`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I have completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Its ok amigo.try what I have done and you will get it. I am sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `-` option you're reading from ["standard input"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29). From the manpage of `head(1)`:

> ```
> when FILE is -, read standard input.
> ```

Your keyboard is the standard input in this case, as your shell doesn't provide another to `head` here. Everytime you provide a line, it will just process it up to 10 times as it's outputting the first 10 lines by default. As your shell will also print the input you provide, you'll see all lines twice.

When you *are* providing a stream to the standard input to `head`, then your keyboard input will not be grabbed. E.g.:

```
echo blaat | head -
```

will make `echo` output "blaat" to standard output and your shell will connect that to standard input of `head` (as expressed by the `|`).

*Note: Without any arguments given `head` will also read from standard input.*

A more useful (random) example for the use in connecting up standard input with head is this:

```
grep error /var/log/syslog | grep -iv apache | head
```

Will print the first 10 lines matching `error`, but not `apache` from `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: is there any use ? I mean where we can use this ?

Comment: @snow What exactly are you referring to? The use in `head` or standard input via keyboard in general? I think the first has been explained in my answer and the the latter is being used very widely in the terminal (entering sudo password for example), just not very common in combination with `head`.

Comment: last words are interesting , could you add a bit more about relation of head & password .

Comment: @snow What? No, passwords and `head` have very few in combination to explain about. I think you're making the wrong connections about my points. There's no relation except that passwords are being read by standard input and that head can also read from standard input. Like 99% of the command line tools.